# How do you find your join position in a server

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Looking for a way to find when you joined a server by position.
For example: If I'm the owner of the server I would be 1 because I joined first, then if I joined after the Owner I would be 2 and if I joined after 20 people join I would be 21 and so on.
Does anyone know a way to figure this out in Node.Js?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`GuildMember.joinedAt`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=joinedAt) property: that will return the date of when you joined the server.
Here's a function that can help you:

```js
function getJoinRank(ID, guild) { // Call it with the ID of the user and the guild
    if (!guild.member(ID)) return; // It will return undefined if the ID is not valid

    let arr = guild.members.array(); // Create an array with every member
    arr.sort((a, b) => a.joinedAt - b.joinedAt); // Sort them by join date

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { // Loop though every element
      if (arr[i].id == ID) return i; // When you find the user, return it's position
    }
}
```

You can also make it return the array, if it's better for you. You could also directly sort the members' collection itself, but remember that you'll have to sort it every time (the client could update it):

```
guild.members.sort((a, b) => a.joinedAt - b.joinedAt);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's anything API wise that would let you do this, your best shot is to run a bot that tracks who joins/leaves and make that structure yourself.

Comment: Dyno has a function for it but I want to make one myself

Comment: There's probably a way to grab some data whenever a user joins/leaves, create a mapped int => int table, first int being Discord user ID second being position joined, fill as people join the server and do checks if that id already exists in your table