# How can i get the join position on Discord servers with my own bot in Python?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to create a whois command that shows the join position. Unfortunately I found only one code for Javascript. But since I'm programming my Discordbot with Python, I need help.

Comment: post any of your own efforts?

Comment: What do you mean by join position?

Comment: in which Position i joined the Server. i mean, I the Owner and i joined First. My Friends are then 2,3,4,...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to [this `discord.js` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54331654/how-do-you-find-your-join-position-in-a-server), we can get the [`Member.joined_at`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.joined_at) date, then count the number of members from `Guild.members` who have lower join dates.  `joined_at` can apparently be `None` in some circumstances, but my code will treat those members as if they don't exist (I think it's for members who have left the guild but for whom we still have an object, but I'm not sure).

```
@commands.guild_only()
@bot.command()
async def position(ctx, *, member: Member = none):
    member = member or ctx.author
    if member.joined_at is None:
        await ctx.send("Could not locate your join date.")
        return
    pos = sum(m.joined_at < member.joined_at for m in ctx.guild.members if m.joined_at is not None)
    await ctx.send(f"You are member #{pos}")
```

Comment: I got the Error: ```AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'command'```
I guess it's because I'm not using ctx, but the normal Discord. You can have a look at my SRC: https://github.com/IBimsEinMystery/ServerPatches

Comment: This should still be demonstrative of how you get the join position of the member.  Just use `message.author` for `member` and send to `message.channel` instead of `ctx`.