# discord.py join position variable shows 0 or 1

Tags: discord.py

Have the problem with variable that should count your server join position, for example creator of server is 1 and then who joined 2,3 and so on, but it shows 1 or 0, what is incorrect? Link where from i use code

[How can i get the join position on Discord servers with my own bot in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59624964/how-can-i-get-the-join-position-on-discord-servers-with-my-own-bot-in-python)
(this question is only one about join position on python)

```
date_format = '%a, %b %d, %Y @ %I:%M %p'
        pos = sum( m.joined_at.strftime( date_format ) < ctx.author.joined_at.strftime( date_format ) for m in ctx.guild.members )
```

**Edited:** error: `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ValueError:  <Member id=3157572775606710941 name='Jhonny' discriminator='9382' bot=False nick='123' guild= Guild id=83938922342333423 name="Test" shard_id=None chunked=False member_count=3>> is not in list`

```
sorted_members = sorted(ctx.guild.members, key=lambda m:m.joined_at)
        ind = sorted_members.index(ctx.author) + 1
```

Comment: You are comparing two times. This returns a boolean result, which is 1 and 0.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to sort the list of members based on `joined_at`

```py
sorted_members = sorted(ctx.guild.members, key=lambda m:m.joined_at)
```

This returns all the member objects in order of joining.
You can then get the index of the object (the join position) and add 1 to get the number you want.

```py
ind = sorted_members.index(ctx.author) + 1
```

Comment: i have an error, or this code was just example?

Comment: @prodbyOleksandr Depends on the error, but this code should work if placed properly

Comment: i edited the question and there is the error

Comment: @prodbyOleksandr Can you print sorted_members and see what it returns?

Comment: it returns [<Member id=myid name='nameofbot' discriminator='mydiscordtag' bot=True nick=None guild=<Guild id=guildid name="nameofguild" shard_id=None chunked=False member_count=3>>]

Comment: Can you print `ctx.guild.members` by itself?

Comment: no members print same thing like i write before

Comment: @prodbyOleksandr `sorted_members` and `ctx.guild.members` are different. Are you sure that they are printing the same?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232594/discussion-between-12944qwerty-and-prodbyoleksandr).